# Redirect from local drive to server

Tags: javascript, php, xampp, localhost, host

I am Writing some php files and testing them on local server (xampp)
My problem is that when i directly open a file in browser by double clicking on it. it shows me local drive path like `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/folder/file.php` i want to change or redirect url of **SELECTIVE FILES** to `http://localhost/folder/file.php`

i think i need some javascript but unable to find how?
PS: i do not want all the files to change url, but **SELECTIVE** files.

Answer (score 0):

PHP files are supposed to be served up by the server, as such if you want to see the interpreted result of your work you need to access the file as the server outputs the file.

```
localhost/folder/file.php
```

If you are double clicking the file name and a browser is opening up, then you should configure your file editor to open up so that you can work on the php file.

Comment: I want to open files in browser but as `http://localhost/folder/file.php` not as `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/folder/file.php`

Answer (score 0):

Just to cover the basics you need to go to the xampp control panel and click start where Apache is. Check if your firewall is blocking the Apache process from starting (I had this error when using Comodo firewall). Then if thats ok you should do what Cups said above.
If that does not work you should open up a terminal (in Linux/OSX) or Command Prompt (in Windows) and type:

> ping localhost

If that give an error you need to look into your Hosts file.